# loading google images with jQuery and json - NOT works in Opera

Tags: jquery, json, image, search

this code works fine in IE8, Chrome, Firefox, but in Opera 11.5 it works ONLY if I uncomment alert line, could anyone explain why?

```
$.ajax({
url:"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=barack%20obama&key=YOUR-GOOGLE-API-KEY",
dataType:"jsonp",
success: function(data){


for (var i = 0; i < data.responseData.results.length; i++){

/* alert(data.responseData.results[i].tbUrl); */

 $('#image-container').append('<img src="' + data.responseData.results[i].tbUrl + '">' + '<br>');

}


}
```

});

here: http://jsonlint.com/ you can view a json response

Answer (score 1):

You need to append `callback=?` to url to "allow" jsonp.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=barack%20obama&callback=?",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data) {


        for (var i = 0; i < data.responseData.results.length; i++) {

            /* alert(data.responseData.results[i].tbUrl); */

            $('#image-container').append('<img src="' + data.responseData.results[i].tbUrl + '">' + '<br>');

        }
    }


});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/genesis/TyDHK/2

Comment: no, just go at http://jsonlint.com/  and paste <pre>https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=barack%20obama&key=YOUR-GOOGLE-API-KEY</pre>

Comment: you will see, that https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=barack%20obama&key=YOUR-GOOGLE-API-KEY retutn json response, while .. ?callback=? returns false

Comment: please look at my edit and fiddle. It's working (you need no key)

Comment: thankU, but it's working fine from Opera on http://jsfiddle.net/genesis/TyDHK/2, but doesn't work FROM OPERA on my local server, no matter with callback=? or without it..( here is the problem

Comment: @drdarwin: then you're probably missing jquery loaded

Comment: you think, I haven't evolved from monkey..)